# cant load custom dataset to cnn pretrained for feature extraction

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

hello i am newbie to all this and i am trying to feed the pretrained CNN VGG16 with a custom dataset of mine and then to achieve feature extraction for every image with numpy. but i am taking this error:'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load_img' really any help appreciate it.thanks

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
dir_images = "C:/Users/.../Desktop/db"
imgs = os.listdir(dir_images)
for imgnm in imgs:
    image = plt.imread(os.path.join(dir_images, imgnm))
img = image.load_img(image, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
features = model.predict(x)
#np.save('features.csv', features)
```

Comment: You are opening the image already with plt.imread, so every time you are overwriting the variable image with new image. Later you want to load the image again, but it is already opened as numpy array what gives you error. You will have rewrite lines 4-7 to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overiding the module `image` of `keras.preprocessing` by your own actual images loaded with matplotlib.

So just change the line

```
image = plt.imread(os.path.join(dir_images, imgnm))
```

into somehting else like

```
arr_image = plt.imread(os.path.join(dir_images, imgnm))
```

and then this error will be gone.

But note that `image.load_img` takes path as input and not actual images of type `ndarray` so you should instead use `load_img` in the loop and remove the matplotlib loading.